# Issue with <T extends Comparable<? super T>>

Tags: java, generics, heap

I have a HeapInterface, and a Heap class with an array-based implementation. I'm trying to make a Heap of the class Integers, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
at HeapArray.<init>(HeapArray.java:16)
at HeapArray.<init>(HeapArray.java:10)
at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

I'll provide the declaration of each class, the constructors, and the test method that produced the error in hopes someone can explain my error...

```
public interface HeapInterface<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {...}

public class HeapArray<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements HeapInterface<T> {
   private T[] heap;
   private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
   private int numberOfEntries;

   public HeapArray() {
      this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
   }//end default constructor

   public HeapArray(int capacity) {
      numberOfEntries = 0;
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      T[] tempHeap = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
      heap = tempHeap;
   }//end alternative constructor

   ...
}

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      HeapInterface<Integer> h = new HeapArray<Integer>();

      for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
         h.add(i);

      System.out.println(h);
   }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `T[] tempHeap = (T[]) new Object[capacity];` this can't be right

Comment: @Zhuinden if you can make that into an answer, you have my upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast an Object[] to a T[] whilst asserting that T is comparable as an Object is not comparable. Try creating a `Comparable[]` and casting it to a `T[]`:

```
  T[] tempHeap = (T[]) new Comparable[capacity];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly... really embarrassed I didn't think of that.  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidWallace I've encountered the problem before. It gives an unchecked cast warning but nothing more.

Comment: @BWalsh Don't forget to accept the answer to remove the question off the unanswered list

Comment: OK, I take it back.  I would have thought that if `T` is `Integer`, then casting `Comparable[]` to `T[]` would be just as bad as casting `Object[]` to `T[]`, since both `Object` and `Comparable` are supertypes of `Integer`.  Honestly, I don't understand why this works.

Comment: @DavidWallace Due to type erasure T becomes a `Comparable` at runtime and we can thus cast an array of comparables to it. Java Generics :D

Comment: @DavidWallace **Here**, you aren't casting to `Integer[]`. You are casting to `T`, which has a bound of `Comparable[]`. If you try to retrieve the array as `T[]`, ie. assign it to an `Integer[]`, you will get the exception.

Comment: Right, yes, thanks Quirliom and @SotiriosDelimanolis.  I came to the same conclusion myself shortly before you both posted.  I just had to think about it for a couple of minutes longer!